# Django template - p tag is closed for no reason

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to elaborate on a django form.as_p() so that I can customize a few fields, but in most cases I just need the simple as_p rendering. So while looping through the fields, I turned most into this:

```
<p>
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
</p>
```

But occaisionally, my html winds up looking like this:

```
<p>
                    </p>
<ul class="errorlist">
    <li>This field is required.</li>
</ul>
<label for="id_name">Name</label>
<input id="id_name" maxlength="200" name="name" type="text" autocomplete="off">
<p></p>
```

with those extraneous p's and the things that I want in p's not in p's.

What might be causing this? I've check and triple checked and I know I'm not missing any closing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML does not permit block elements like `ul` inside `p` elements. So when your field has an error, which is rendered with a `ul`, your browser helpfully closes the `p` to make it valid. (What you're looking at is the browser's DOM representation, not the actual rendered HTML which won't contain the magic close elements: do "view source" to see this.)

You should move the error tag out of the `p`. If you like, you can wrap the whole thing in something like a `div`.

Comment: Years of web design and I've never run into this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't initialize your form in the html. 
See the following example:

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in my_form %}
    <p>{{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```